# Continous marginal distributions, but conditional distribution is discrete

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Is it possible to find a random vector $(X, Y)$ such that marginal distribution of $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, but the conditional distribution of $X|Y$ (i.e $X$ given $Y$) and that of $Y|X$ are discrete?

I was reading about conditional distributions, and got this doubt? Is there any example for such random variables, or is it impossible to find such random variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for questions regarding *uncorrelated but not independent* normal (a.k.a. Gaussian) random variables here on math.SE or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) for examples.